# How to create user profiles urls like /@username with .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this existing code in my .htaccess file for removing .php from the end of url and adding a slash.
I also have custom error pages specified.
Now I'm trying to add a rule to /user.php?username=something to /@something
but it goes to 404

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php

RewriteEngine on

### THIS IS NOT WORKING ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^@([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)/$ /user.php?username=$1 [QSA,R=302]

### MAP /EXAMPLE/ TO /EXAMPLE.PHP ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+?)/$ /$1.php [END]


### FORCE TRAILING SLASH WHEN ABSENT FOR NON-FILES ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R=302,L]


### REDIRECT (DIR)/INDEX.PHP TO (DIR)/ ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.+/)?index\.php$ /$1 [R=302,L]


### REDIRECT /EXAMPLE.PHP TO /EXAMPLE/ ###
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

I tried the following code but it's only working if other rules are not in the .htaccess file.

I need to make it work with the other rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^@([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)/$ /user.php?username=$1 [QSA,R=302]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^@([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)/$` - your pattern demands a slash at the very end there, so `/@something/` would match, but `/@something` doesn't.